# The opposite of "shell protection"

Tags: terminology

In security, we speak about different strategies of protection. Mainly, there are three to consider. First kind, usually called *shell protection* corresponds to the act of preventing the intrusion before the access. For instance, a door, fence, password on a website or silver galvanization of the utensils.

That's usually very powerful and easy to maintain. Occasionally, there's a breach and then, we have problems, unless there's also the other kind of security implemented. Here, we're talking about smoke dispensers, mazes, ambulating patrols, honey pots, fake repos etc.

What would be a good term for that? (Extra great if it's formal'ish.)

The one I've been using is *impregnation protection* but I'm not sure if it makes sense, let alone is correct linguistically, let aloner comprehensible to regular people.

(The third is deterrent protection and not relevant to this question.)

Comment: Also, _shell protection_ seems to be a very specialist term.

Comment: Are you asking about [**defense in depth**](https://www.fortinet.com/resources/cyberglossary/defense-in-depth)?  (*Impregnation protection* does not really make sense - it sounds like you're talking about [birth control](https://medlineplus.gov/birthcontrol.html).)

Comment: @stangdon Haha, that's *contraceptive* but I see your point. It might be my Swedish spooking but isn't e.g. *impregnating shoes* an act of making the leather water resistant by immersing the surface in a fat, water repelling substance? [Meaning 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impregnate)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes, you're right that *impregnating* can also mean any act of infusing a material with something else.  But it's more common (I think) for it to have its more literal meaning of "making pregnant".

Comment: Are you asking if there exists such a term, or are you looking for suggestions?

Comment: @gotube Excellent discrimination of intentions! To be honest, I assumed there **was** for sure a de facto default term for it, so that's my original goal. However, as your inquiry clearly made apparent, I may be forced to alter my expectations. So, at this stage, I'm fine with suggestions as well. Did you have one? Go nuts!  :)

Comment: I don't know one. Is there such a term in your language? If so, what do translation dictionaries tell you the English equivalent is? And if not, why do you think English would have one?

Comment: @gotube It was more **hoped** than **thought**. Also, English has this wonderful elasticity and is also the lingua franca for tech stuff, so it wasn't that far fetched, in my opinion. As for my language, well, the jury is still out on the **correct** and **agreed** term but it if anything, it would be something with impregnation.   :(

Comment: Contrary to @PeterJennings's assessment, this question is about a very specific term in a very specific technical area and people in that area are much more likely to have an idea. It's not off-topic on ELU but if there's a security.se (that is primarily in English) then I would expect that site to more likely get good responses.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure I agree entirely. While exemplified by a specific scenario (or, rather, set of scenarios), the idea of preventing something is applicable in a linguistic sense (although, admittedly, I'm stretching it a bit now). Prevention prior to, during or after the act of an intrusion is a distinction that, in my opinion, should be part of the language (since there's no formal definition, as far I'm aware). I would say it's an overlap but the question intends to aim on broader context than specific technical area. It just uses that as an example.

Comment: @jsw29 I have not, indeed. I chose not to since I'm rather certain there's no convention based in the industry. It varies between different geographical areas and within different fields. I presumed that asking there would only lead to either a lengthy discussion on how to implement different security solutions or a referral to ELL (possibly both). I'd love to see it discussed from the non-technical layman's perspective, though. The need for the taxonomy rarely arises when I communicate with security folk, namely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of "shell protection", but I do have a set of words that should work for you:

- **Deterrence**: What you can do to prevent an attack from being launched.
- **Prevention**: What you can do to halt a launched attack before a breach.
- **Mitigation**: What you can do to limit an attack after a breach.

This is vocabulary I picked up while dealing with ransomware protection professionals. An example of mitigation with ransomware would be preventing old backups from being automatically deleted.

For example, according to [HYPR](https://www.hypr.com/security-encyclopedia/mitigation):

> Mitigation, or Attack Mitigation, is the reduction in severity or seriousness of an event. In cybersecurity, mitigation is centered around strategies to limit the impact of a threat against data in custody.
> ...
> Mitigation strategies are used by many companies and public-sector entities to isolate and minimize the damage or impact of a threat until a problem can be counter-measured.
> ...
> Example:
> "Even though the government's systems were breached, the mitigation strategy in place prevented additional security incidents while appropriate countermeasures were implemented to answer the question of how to defend against future similar attacks."

Comment: This is not bad at all. And I like that it's abstract enough to be applicable in a wide range of situations, too... I'll make an addition to the bullet list to make it (in my opinion) perfect. Feel free to rollback if you disagree. It's helpful anyway and my opinion may be different from the majority's, anyway.